# Read-Only Domain Controller thinks it is on a Public Network

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windwos 2012 R2 Read-Only Domain Controller in a remote site. Although I suppose everything is configured correctly, it keeps thinking that it is on a public network. I have checked the related question [Domain Controller thinks its on a Public Network](https://serverfault.com/questions/362374/domain-controller-thinks-its-on-a-public-network) but it did not help me.

- unplugged and reconnected the cable - no success
- restarted NLA service - nosuccess
- disabled IPv6 (and restarted NLA again) - no success
- tried IPCONFIG /RENEW - no success (the ip is fixed anyway)
- rebooted - no success

There are two NICs physically, but one is deactivated. The other has a fixed address 10.0.50.3/24, gateway 10.0.50.1, ip connectivity to the main site is functional. The network 10.0.50.0/24 exists in *AD Sites and Services* (also when checking this from the RODC itself) and is assigned to the correct site.

Unless I learn yet another idea here, I am close to assuming that thgis is a design flaw of the concept of RODC and that I ought to promote (rather: reinstall the role) that box to a RWDC ...

Comment: Can you ping the default gateway? Does it answer when pinged?

Comment: Look at: http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles.aspx and http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles.aspx

Comment: @Massimo Yes, fine (after all the working connection to the hub site runs over it)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen this is not so obvious; some routers will happily route traffic but will not respond to ping requests; if this happens on the default gateway, Windows will have *lots* of troubles identifying which network it's connected to.

Comment: @Massimo Agreed. Not responding to ping might be considered a security feature. (Which casts some doubts on making pingability a requirement; if I were responsible, I'd replace a ping test with an arp test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `dcdiag` revealed that there were problems with the MachineAccount test (all SNA records failed). Running `dcdiag /fix` fixed this (at least enough to almost instantly trigger correct network discovery as "domain" instead of "public").