# Change Windows 2012 R2 Network from Public to Domain

Tags: networking, domain, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, local-area-network

I upgraded the Network Card Drivers for my Domain Controller but now it is seeing the local lan as a PUBLIC network which is messing with my firewall rules.

How do I switch it back to DOMAIN?

Comment: Check the answers here, many still apply for server 2012r2 http://serverfault.com/questions/362374/domain-controller-thinks-its-on-a-public-network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Powershell to achieve this. First you have to list network profile

`Get-NetConnectionProfile`

Use interface index to change the network interface to domain.

`Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex 7 -NetworkCategory Domain`

Comment: I tried that, and I am getting the error: set-netconnectionprofile : Unable to set NetworkCategory to 'DomainAuthenticated'.  This NetworkCategory type will be
set automatically when authenticated to a domain network.

Comment: Be sure that you are using the rigth interface Index

Comment: Had the same error as @KarlHenselin. Index was right. Had to remove the server from the domain, then rejoin.

Answer (score 10):

try

`net stop nlasvc`  as admin

if this works, you can set this service (nlasvc) to "start delayed"

Comment: This is how I was able to resolve the issue on my system after a power outage made this happen on my desktop.  Using the Powershell method only resulted in "Unable to set NetworkCategory to 'DomainAuthenticated'."

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer... https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/98f41513-df6f-4065-975a-6d6dc2308a94/server-2012-r2-change-network-location-from-public-to-private

Reboot or disable/enable the NIC afterwards.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/527464)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).